# How to join Tables as they are pivoted and its a survey data?

Tags: sql

I have two tables. Table 1 data table:

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EGbe.png)

And table 2 ref_table

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeCML.png)

I want to join these two tables and I want to add key column in it accordingly.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: What have you tried?  You can join two queries.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Welcome. I'd suggest you to see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - this can improve your chances to get help. Good luck.

Comment: Well thankyou for this im new here i will try to be ask more explanatory questions :)